# Hide error language from bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a simple shell script that tests whether a password is correct (or not) against an Apple Open Directory (LDAP) server.

What I'd like is simply to lose the gobblygook error message "Authentication for node /LDAPv3/1..."  and instead insert my own language such as "password does not match".

Here's what happens now:

```
bash-3.2# test-password 

Enter username you'd like to test password for:
jdoe

Enter Password to test for jdoe
asdasdasd
Authentication for node /LDAPv3/127.0.0.1 failed. (-14090, eDSAuthFailed)
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14090 (eDSAuthFailed)
```

What I'd prefer is:

```
bash-3.2# test-password 

Enter username you'd like to test password for:
jdoe

Enter Password to test for jdoe
asdasdasd
 Password matches!
```

So I just need to know a way so that the std out error message is muffled...

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin export PATH
echo
echo Enter username you\'d like to test password for:
read USERNAME

echo
echo Enter Password to test for "$USERNAME"
read PASSWORD
/usr/bin/dscl /LDAPv3/127.0.0.1 auth $USERNAME $PASSWORD

if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
       echo "Password is correct"
       exit 0

fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just throw away standard output and error:

```
/usr/bin/dscl /LDAPv3/127.0.0.1 auth $USERNAME $PASSWORD >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Unless the `dscl` program does something devious like open up your `/dev/tty` device for writing, that should take care of everything.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on where the error message is being written. Well-behaved UNIX programs write their errors to stderr.

```
/usr/bin/dscl /LDAPv3/127.0.0.1 auth $USERNAME $PASSWORD 2> /dev/null  # stderr
/usr/bin/dscl /LDAPv3/127.0.0.1 auth $USERNAME $PASSWORD  > /dev/null  # stdout
/usr/bin/dscl /LDAPv3/127.0.0.1 auth $USERNAME $PASSWORD &> /dev/null  # both
```

For what it's worth, you can combine this with the `if` statement. Also, no need for the explicit `/usr/bin` path in front.

```
if dscl /LDAPv3/127.0.0.1 auth $USERNAME $PASSWORD 2> /dev/null; then
    : # success
else
    : # failure
fi
```

Comment: John, thanks, your answer was also correct. I appreciate the detail.